# Can't use computed property in data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-reactivity

I have an array in my data:

```
data () {
  return {
    steps: [
      {
        disabled: this.someCheck
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And a computed property:

```
computed: {
  ...mapGetters({
    getFinishedSteps: 'jobFound/getFinishedSteps'
  }),

  someCheck () {
    let x = true
    for (const val of this.getFinishedSteps) {
      if (val === ('address_information' || 'contact_information' || 'financiel_information' || 'identity_information')) {
        x = false
      }
    }
    return x
  }
}
```

And the template:

```html
<ProgressContent
  v-for="(step, n) of steps"
  :key="n"
/>
```

And the ProgressContent component:

```
props: {
  step: {
    type: Object,
    default: () => ({
      disabled: false
    })
  },
}
```

I want to pass the return value of the `someCheck` computed property into the `disabled` value in the data but in the `ProgressContent` component the `disabled` value is not there (it's empty).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assign a computed to a data property while the data is initializing.  Even if you could, it would not be reactive, it would only occur once.  If the computed changed, the data property would not.

You could create `steps` as a *computed*:

```js
computed: {
  ...mapGetters({
    getFinishedSteps: 'jobFound/getFinishedSteps'
  }),
  someCheck () {
    // ...
  },
  steps() {
    return [{  disabled: this.someCheck }]
  }
}
```

Or you could use a *watch*:

```js
data() {
  return {
    steps: [{ disabled: null }]
  }
},
computed: {
  ...mapGetters({
    getFinishedSteps: 'jobFound/getFinishedSteps'
  }),
  someCheck () {
    // ...
  }
},
watch: {
  someCheck: {
    handler(newValue) {
      this.steps[0].disabled = newValue;
    },
    immediate: true
  }
},
```